# Image getPixel giving wrong color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

I am trying to pick the color from a horizontal bar with imageViews by reading their pixel values which is sort of horizontal colour picker

but I am unable to retrieve the proper colour there is some problem in sending the points of the knob because of the hierarchy
 - View
  - UIImageview (Red)
  - UIImageview (Green)
  - UIimageview (Blue)
 -  etc…

Below is the code of it

storyboard:I am trying to pick the color from a horizontal bar with imageViews by reading their pixel values which is sort of horizontal colour picker

but I am unable to retrieve the proper colour there is some problem in sending the points of the knob because of the hierarchy
 - View
  - UIImageview (Red)
  - UIImageview (Green)
  - UIimageview (Blue)
 -  etc…

Below is the code of it

storyboard:

[image]

```
#import "EffViewController.h"
#import "TouchMoveGestureRecognizer.h"
@interface EffViewController ()

@end

@implementation EffViewController

@synthesize colorPicker,sliders,sliderValues,picker;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    for (ColorPickerImageView *colorPickers in _colorPickerArray) {

        colorPickers.pickedColorDelegate = self;
    }

    //colorPicker.pickedColorDelegate = self;

    TouchMoveGestureRecognizer* gr = [[TouchMoveGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [picker addGestureRecognizer: gr];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getTheColorPickerData:) name:@"getTheColorPickerData" object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) pickedColor:(UIColor*)color atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
    [picker setHidden:false];
    self.view.backgroundColor = color;
//    Convert point Positions from colorpickerview to main view
    CGPoint pointInViewCoords = [self.view convertPoint:point fromView:colorPicker];

    //[picker setCenter:pointInViewCoords];

    CGColorRef cgcolor = [color CGColor];
    int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(cgcolor);
    if (numComponents == 4){
        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(cgcolor);
        for(UISlider *slider in sliders)
            [slider setValue: components[[slider tag]-1]*255.0f];

        for(UITextField *text in sliderValues){
            int intValue = components[[text tag]-1]*255;
            [text setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intValue]];
        }
    }

}



- (void)getTheColorPickerData:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // 1
    //UIEvent *event = notification.userInfo[@"events"];
    NSSet *touches = notification.userInfo[@"touches"];

    UITouch* t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint Worldpoint = [t locationInView: self.colorPickerViewFrame];
    //point.y = picker.frame.origin.y;
    NSLog(@"World Points x:%f  y:%f",Worldpoint.x,Worldpoint.y);

    [picker setHidden:false];
    CGPoint point = picker.frame.origin;//[[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    point.y = picker.frame.size.height/2;
    UIControl *control = picker;
    NSLog(@"Points x:%f  y:%f",point.x,point.y);
    NSLog(@"Color Picker Points x :%f  y:%f  w:%f  h:%f",[colorPicker frame].origin.x,[colorPicker frame].origin.y,[colorPicker frame].size.width,[colorPicker frame].size.height);

    for (ColorPickerImageView *colorPickers in _colorPickerArray) {


    if (CGRectContainsPoint([colorPickers frame], point)) {
        // control.center = point;
        //[colorPicker touchesEnded:[event allTouches] withEvent:event];
        [colorPicker imageSelectionEnded:point];

        }
    }
}
```

TouchMoveGesture

```
#import "TouchMoveGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation TouchMoveGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    UITouch* t = [touches anyObject];
    _ptOffset = [t locationInView: self.view];

//    if(![self isInsideTheBoundary:_ptOffset]){
//        return;
//    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    UITouch* t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pt = [t locationInView: self.view.superview];
    float ptYtemp;

//    if(![self isInsideTheBoundary:pt]){
//        return;
//    }



    if ((pt.x < 295.0f && pt.x > 25.0f) == NO) {
        return;
    }

    pt.x -= _ptOffset.x;
    ptYtemp = pt.y;
    pt.y -= _ptOffset.y;

    if ((pt.y < 26.0f && pt.y > 24.0f) == NO) {

        pt.y=ptYtemp;
    }

    CGRect r = self.view.frame;
    r.origin.x = pt.x;
    self.view.frame = r;

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _ptOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getTheColorPickerData"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:@{@"touches":touches,
                                                                 @"events":event}];
}


-(BOOL) isInsideTheBoundary :(CGPoint) location {

    BOOL isInsideBoundary = NO;
   // NSLog(@"Location x:%f  y:%f",location.x,location.y);
    if (location.x < 320.0f && location.x > 0.0f) {
        if (location.y < 31.0f && location.y > 26.0f) {

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

ColorPickerImageView

```
#import "ColorPickerImageView.h"
#import "EffViewController.h"
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>

@implementation ColorPickerImageView

@synthesize lastColor;
@synthesize pickedColorDelegate;


- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    if (self.hidden==YES) {
        //color wheel is hidden, so don't handle  this as a color wheel event.
        [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self]; //where image was tapped
    }

-(void)imageSelectionEnded:(CGPoint)point {

    if (self.hidden==YES) {
        //color wheel is hidden, so don't handle  this as a color wheel event.
    //  [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    self.lastColor = [self getPixelColorAtLocation:point];
    NSLog(@"color %@",lastColor);
    [pickedColorDelegate pickedColor:(UIColor*)self.lastColor atPoint:point];

}

- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
    UIColor* color = nil;
    CGImageRef inImage = self.image.CGImage;
    // Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};
/** Extra Added code for Resized Images ****/
    float xscale = w / self.frame.size.width;
    float yscale = h / self.frame.size.height;
    point.x = point.x * xscale;
    point.y = point.y * yscale;
 /** ****************************************/

/** Extra Code Added for Resolution ***********/
    CGFloat x = 1.0;
    if ([self.image respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) x = self.image.scale;
/*********************************************/
    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory 
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the 
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    if (data != NULL) {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y. 
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
//      int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));


        int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x))*x; //Replacement for Resolution
        int alpha =  data[offset];
        int red = data[offset+1]; 
        int green = data[offset+2]; 
        int blue = data[offset+3]; 
        NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data) { free(data); }

    return color;
}



- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage {

    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits 
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is 
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}



@end
```